# What do Coaches do?

Tags: word-usage

Do Coaches coach and Teachers teach? The essence of my question is, is coaching exactly the same as teaching. My understanding is that the nouns may always be interchangeable but the verbs are not.
In the Cambridge English Dictionary it refers to coaching as relating to specialised training of an individual or small group.[CAMBRIDGE ENGLISH DICTIONARY](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coaching)

Comment: I see a difference, but you should probably indicate what research you've done (e.g. dictionary definitions) and – depending on what they say – why this doesn't leave you convinced one way or another.

Comment: When you say the nouns are interchangeable, are you saying the nouns "coach" and "teacher" are interchangeable? Or are you saying that the verbal nouns (gerund forms) "coaching" and "teaching" are interchangeable? Either way, they may be interchangeable only insofar as they may be understandable, but I imagine some of the results of interchanging the two in random instances would be pretty unidiomatic in many cases.

Comment: @Zebrafish The former is what I am relating too as interchangeable nouns

Comment: @TripeHound Thanks, I have edited the post.

Comment: The nouns are used in different contexts (e.g. coach in sports, teacher in musical instrument), but is there a particular context you have in mind? Different words can have essentially the same meaning but be used in different ways. Is this a question about educational methods (what does a sports coach do that's different to a piano teacher) or the contexts in which words are used?

Comment: They're obviously similar, right? But you can't always replace one with the other. Are 'training' and 'learning' identical?

Comment: @Stuart F No it is not a question about educational methods. A common phrase in Chinese English Text Books is Coaches teach Sports. In my opinion this is wrong on two accounts. You can be coached in things other than sports and secondly Coaches do not teach in the generally accepted sense of the word teach.  (Physical education Teacher vs Football Coach). What I am getting at is, if there is an overlap, but they are not the same. Then you can only use the phrase Coaches teach with a qualifying statement and even then it may be debatable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Since the underlying verbs are generally not interchangeable, neither are the nouns.

While there is overlap between the verbs ***teach*** and ***coach***, their definitions are different. From Mirriam-Webster:

> [**teach**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/teach), *verb*
>
> 1. a: to cause to know something: *taught them a trade*
>      b: to cause to know how: *is teaching me to drive*
>      c: to accustom to some action or attitude: *teach students to think for themselves*
>      d: to cause to know the disagreeable consequences of some action: *I'll teach you to come home late*
> 2. to guide the studies of
> 3. to impart the knowledge of: *teach algebra*
> 4. a: to instruct by precept, example, or experience
>      b: to make known and accepted: *experience teaches us our limitations*
> 5. to conduct instruction regularly in: *teach school*
>
> [**coach**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coach), *intransitive verb*
>
> 1. to go in a coach  (*not relevant to this discussion*)
> 2. to instruct, direct, or prompt as a coach: *When an injury ended his playing career, he decided to coach.*
>
> *transitive verb*
>
> 1. to train intensively (as by instruction and demonstration): *coach pupils*, *The lawyer coached the witness.*
> 2. to act as coach of: *coach tennis*, *coach a team*

And while *coach* is most commonly used in relation to physical activity, it can also be used in an academic sense. The OED has:

> [**coach**](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/34955#eid9214382), *verb*
>
> 3. University colloquial, etc.  [see [coach n. 3](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/34954#eid9212908)]
>      a. *transitive*. To prepare (a candidate) for an examination; to instruct in special subjects; to tutor; also, to train for an athletic contest, as a boat-race.

If I was to summarize:

- *teach* is primarily concerned with the imparting of (new) knowledge to students who do not already posses that knowledge.
- *coach* is more concerned with encouragement (in both physical and academic disciplines: getting the person being coached to do things they'd much rather not bother with), improvement through repetition, and improving technique (of things that are broadly already known).

Therefore, while *part* of teaching may include *coaching* [students in better ways of doing things they already know], and part of coaching may include *teaching* [e.g. new techniques of throwing a football], for the most part, your opening sentence is correct: ***Teachers teach and coaches coach***. Since the underlying verbs are generally not interchangeable, neither are the nouns.

Comment: I used C.E.D.and the interchangeability of the 2 nouns is more debatable. However you have confirmed what I have always though, and to be honest, been quite vocal about..  Teachers teach and coaches coach. Thank you